# Django: ImportError: No module named 'services'

Tags: python, django

I have following project setup.

```
myproject/
   manage.py
   requirement.txt
   myproject/
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
   services/
       __init__.py
       models.py
       views.py
       urls.py
       management/
          __init__.py 
          commands/
             __init__.py
             myscript.py
```

In `myscript.py` file I want to import models from `services` app. I have added following line.

```
from services.models import TwitterRawFeeds, TwitterUserDetails, MarkedTweets
```

But I am getting error `ImportError: No module named 'services'`

I tried relative import as well..

```
from .models import TwitterRawFeeds, TwitterUserDetails, MarkedTweets
```

this time i get error like `Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

What i am missing here, need help.

Installed apps section..

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_mongoengine',
 'services',
)
```

Comment: is `services` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes. It it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presence of `__init__.py` makes it a python module, so add `__init__.py` into the `management` directory and it should work.

Run the command with `python manage.py myscript` from the `myproject` folder, it should work, apparently you are using `python myscript.py` to run it, in which case, `mysript.py` will not read the `settings.py`, there is no way your script will load `services` app. Running the `myscript.py` with `python manage.py myscript` on the other hand loads all the settings and it works :)

```
myproject/
   manage.py
   requirement.txt
   myproject/
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
   services/
       __init__.py
       models.py
       views.py
       urls.py
       management/
          __init__.py # add this file
          commands/
             __init__.py
             myscript.py
```

Comment: can you post the INSTALLED_APPS section of your settings ?

Comment: what version of django are u using ? `mongoengine` doesnt support the latest version of django. I believe it supports only 1.8 ? But `django-mongoengine` might support latest one

Comment: I hav `Django 1.7`

Comment: I am not seeing the `apps.py` file in the `services` app.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib I dont think apps.py is needed for management command, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: all looks good to me, can you post the complete error in the console

Comment: I have already added error. I am runing script as `python myscript.py` only

Comment: Haha.. use it as `python manage.py myscript ` from the `myproject` folder. thats how you should use the command. When you use `python myscript.py` obvoisely it will not load the settings module and settings.py is where you mentioned the `services` app

Comment: I will have to provide full path of myscript.py right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141343/discussion-between-rrmerugu-and-shri).

Answer (score 2):

Missed an `__init__.py` inside `management/` dir? As you have it `management/` is not a python module. It's just a plain directory. Put an `__init__.py` inside it.

Comment: What about `from ...models import TwitterRawFeeds, TwitterUserDetails, MarkedTweets` ?

Comment: then i get `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: is it related to environment?